# Merge string cells on unique keys when some conditions are met

Tags: mysql

```
ID  TELEFON     CULOARE    piesa1   piesa2  piesa3  piesa4
1   telefon1    culoare1    0N        0N      0N      0N
1   telefon1    culoare1    14Y       0N      0N      0N
2   telefon2    culoare2    0N        8Y      0N      0N
2   telefon2    culoare2    0N        0N      4Y      0N
3   telefon3    culoare3    0N        0N      0N      0Y
3   telefon3    culoare3    0N        0N      0N      0N
3   telefon3    culoare3    0N        0N      0N      0N
3   telefon3    culoare3    0N        0N      5Y      0N
4   telefon4    Neutru      8N        0N      0N      0N
4   telefon4    Neutru      0N        0N      1N      0N
4   telefon4    Neutru      0N        0N      0N      7Y
```

I have a result set like this, but I want to somehow merge the rows where ID column is duplicate and leave only the cells where the value ends with a 'Y' or with 'N' but with precedeing number greater than 0.
I manage to do this only with numbers by adding `SUM` agg function and grouping by unique identifier of the row which in my case would be TELEFON+CULOARE columns.

The query for this result:

```
SELECT tt.id as `#`
,t.telefon as TELEFON
, IFNULL(c.culoare,'Neutru') as CULOARE
, (IF(p.piesa = 'piesa1', CONCAT(tt.total_piese,tt.is_stoc_min),'0N')) AS piesa1
,(IF(p.piesa = 'piesa2', CONCAT(tt.total_piese,tt.is_stoc_min),'0N')) AS piesa2
,(IF(p.piesa = 'piesa3', CONCAT(tt.total_piese,tt.is_stoc_min),'0N')) AS piesa3
,(IF(p.piesa = 'piesa4', CONCAT(tt.total_piese,tt.is_stoc_min),'0N')) AS piesa4 
,tt.total_piese
,tt.is_stoc_min
FROM telefon as t LEFT JOIN
total_piese as tt
ON t.id = tt.id_telefon
LEFT JOIN culoare as c
ON c.id  = tt.id_culoare
LEFT JOIN piesa as p
ON p.id = tt.id_piesa
ORDER BY t.id;
```

My desire results would be like this:

```
TELEFON     CULOARE   piesa1    piesa2  piesa3  piesa4
telefon1    culoare1    14Y       0N      0N      0N
telefon2    culoare2    0N        8Y      4Y      0N
telefon3    culoare3    0N        0N      5Y      0Y
telefon4    Neutru      8N        0N      1N      7Y
```

I have a query that return the merged rows but without the 'Y' or 'N' at the end of the value:

```
SELECT tt.id as `#`
,t.telefon as TELEFON
, IFNULL(c.culoare,'Neutru') as CULOARE
,SUM(IF(p.piesa = 'piesa1', tt.total_piese,0)) AS piesa1
,SUM(IF(p.piesa = 'piesa2', tt.total_piese,0)) AS piesa2
,SUM(IF(p.piesa = 'piesa3', tt.total_piese,0)) AS piesa3
,SUM(IF(p.piesa = 'piesa4',tt.total_piese,0)) AS piesa4 
,tt.stoc_min
 FROM telefon as t LEFT JOIN
 total_piese as tt
 ON t.id = tt.id_telefon
 LEFT JOIN culoare as c
 ON c.id  = tt.id_culoare
 LEFT JOIN piesa as p
 ON p.id = tt.id_piesa
 GROUP BY t.Telefon,c.Culoare
 ORDER BY t.id;
```

Comment: Am I wrong if I correct your desired result to : line2 :  `0N 8Y 4Y 0N` / line 3 : `0N 0N 5Y 0Y` / line4: `8N 0N 1N 7Y`

Comment: Yes, you are right, adjusted the question as per your comment, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's a little bit hard to give you a better (or more optimized) answer, as we don't have the "basic data", but already a result.

Anyway, you could use your first attempt as a subquery, using `max` on the piesa fields. (Cause any number will be greater than 0, and Y is greater than N, so `MAX` should give you the desired output)

```
select id as `#`, telefon, culoare,
max(piesa1) as piesa1,
max(piesa2) as piesa2,
max(piesa3) as piesa3,
max(piesa4) as piesa4
from
  (SELECT 
     tt.id 
    ,t.telefon as TELEFON
    ,IFNULL(c.culoare,'Neutru') as CULOARE
    ,(IF(p.piesa = 'piesa1', CONCAT(tt.total_piese,tt.is_stoc_min),'0N')) AS piesa1
    ,(IF(p.piesa = 'piesa2', CONCAT(tt.total_piese,tt.is_stoc_min),'0N')) AS piesa2
    ,(IF(p.piesa = 'piesa3', CONCAT(tt.total_piese,tt.is_stoc_min),'0N')) AS piesa3
    ,(IF(p.piesa = 'piesa4', CONCAT(tt.total_piese,tt.is_stoc_min),'0N')) AS piesa4 
    ,tt.total_piese
    ,tt.is_stoc_min
  FROM telefon as t LEFT JOIN
    total_piese as tt ON t.id = tt.id_telefon
  LEFT JOIN culoare as c ON c.id  = tt.id_culoare
  LEFT JOIN piesa as p ON p.id = tt.id_piesa) s
GROUP BY id, telefon, culoare
ORDER BY Id
```

or probably (untested) use the max directly in your query

```
SELECT tt.id as `#`
,t.telefon as TELEFON
,IFNULL(c.culoare,'Neutru') as CULOARE
,max((IF(p.piesa = 'piesa1', CONCAT(tt.total_piese,tt.is_stoc_min),'0N'))) AS piesa1
,max((IF(p.piesa = 'piesa2', CONCAT(tt.total_piese,tt.is_stoc_min),'0N'))) AS piesa2
,max((IF(p.piesa = 'piesa3', CONCAT(tt.total_piese,tt.is_stoc_min),'0N'))) AS piesa3
,max((IF(p.piesa = 'piesa4', CONCAT(tt.total_piese,tt.is_stoc_min),'0N'))) AS piesa4 
FROM telefon as t LEFT JOIN
total_piese as tt
ON t.id = tt.id_telefon
LEFT JOIN culoare as c
ON c.id  = tt.id_culoare
LEFT JOIN piesa as p
ON p.id = tt.id_piesa
GROUP BY tt.Id, t.telefon, c.culoare
ORDER BY t.id;
```

Comment: With the data that I have now both queries work perfectly. Will test with the production data and mark as the accepted answer if everything is fine. Thanks a lot,.